# MS Access most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am brand new to querying, so please be patient. I looked at one of the posted topics, and it almost works for me. I just need to be able to pull in one more field.

Here is my Data:

[image: my data]

Here is what I am trying to do with the Data. I want the most recent data for Each item And XorZ. There will be 2 rows for each item, one with X and one with Z. They will show the max date, and bring back the value on that date.

Example:

[image]

I tried using this which works.

```
SELECT Item, MAX(Date), XorZ
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Item, XorZ
ORDER BY ITEM
```

It doesn't work once I try to add Value to the Select though. I get "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Value' as a part of an aggregate function. Then when I added Value to "Group By", the data output isn't bringing back just the newest date for each Item and XorZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the value related to item, XorZ and max_date
you should join your table  with the subselect  for max_date

```
   SELECT Item, Date, XorZ, value 
   from MyTable
   INNER JOIN (

       SELECT Item, MAX(Date) max_date, XorZ
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY Item, XorZ
       ) t on t.max_date = MyTable.daye 
            and t.Item = MyTable.Item 
             and t.XorZ = MyTable.XorZ
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this.  Can you explain to me the ) t on t.max_date  section?  Is that an alias or shortening of something? I saw this in the original code for this and couldn't figure it out. Does it need to be t or is that something I can just select?

Comment: t is an alias for the subselect. you can name it whatever you want

Comment: Started over and it works! Not sure what I was doing wrong, but now I can see the right way.Thank you.

Comment: @MRiley  .. the t is the table name alias  of the table created  by using the subquery  .. a subquery return a result that correspond to a table result set  .. and is possible use this result in a join  .. that tipically is the way the tables are related  each others ..hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

Sub-select it...

```
SELECT xcurr.date
, xcurr.Item
, xcurr.XorZ
, xval.value
FROM MyTable xval INNER JOIN (
SELECT Item, XorZ, MAX(Date) AS [date]
FROM #MyTable 
GROUP BY Item, XorZ, XorZ
) AS xcurr
ON xcurr.Item = xval.Item 
AND xcurr.XorZ = xval.XorZ
AND xcurr.Date = xval.Date
ORDER BY item, XorZ
```

Here is what the results would look like:

[image]

Trying adding a primary key to the table.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing where this brings in "Value".